# What is "sed s_.*/_" doing?

Tags: sed

I've just encountered this sed expression and could not figure out exactly what it means. I've performed a google search previously. I'd appreciate any help.

```
sed 's_.*/__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a way to remove everything up to the last slash in a string:

```
$ echo "hello/a/b/c" | sed 's_.*/__' 
c
```

`sed` replacements are on the form `sed 's/find/replace/'`. However, you can use other delimiters such as `_`, making it look like `sed 's_find_replace_'`.

If you then happen to replace with nothing, you get: `sed 's_find__'`. Now, instead of `find` place `.*/` and you'll have `sed 's_.*/__'`.